# Node function variable is not a function

Tags: node.js

I have the following:

```
// helpers.js
exports.getIt = function getIt(data, cb) {...}
```

And a file that wants to use the getIt function:

```
// getter.js
var helpers = require('./helpers')
var getIt = helpers.getIt;

getIt({}, function(){
    ...
});
```

Just recently after some updates, this all of a sudden throws an error:

> getIt is not a function

If I call getIt like this though:

```
helpers.getIt({}, function(){
    ...
});
```

It works just fine. This is okay, but I have the former setup through the site, I really don't want to have to go and replace all of these if there is an easy fix. What causes this to not work?

Comment: what were the updates?

Comment: Thats strange because it should work. Try the below in your getter.js:                                                      var getIt= require('./helpers').getIt;

Comment: It is impossible. Maybe you use some kind of `requre` hook?

Comment: In order for this question to be answerable, you will likely need to supply an example that reproduces the error described. The code you've given here works fine.

Comment: If `helpers.getIt` is a function but `getIt` is not, then it sounds like something is overwriting the value of `getIt` after the `getIt = helpers.getIt` line.